# Mobile browsers c# asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I was just shutting off the pc at work, and I had to quickly check if something was fixed. But I clicked on my mobile google chrome browser for the desktop and went to test if a bug was fixed or not.

This is where the trouble started, all of a sudden I couldn't hold session. I could login on the web application, but I couldn't hold session. Weird character strings were put in the url each time I logged in but I just couldn't get my browser to hold session. I checked the browser settings, I deleted all cookies, I restarted the browser, etc. Nothing helped to hold session.

While testing I noticed I was using my mobile google chrome browser, where after I checked with the normal google chrome for desktops I was able to hold session.

Im using the normal asp.net authentication implementation, nothing important is custom. But its rather disturbing for maybe future expansions to mobile platforms.
Any of you people know what could've caused this error? Is it an error in google chrome (mobile)? Is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a file called generic.browser in a folder called App_Browsers and put this in it:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="GenericDownlevel">
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="cookies" value="true" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

This will fix the problem that cookies aren't enabled. Apperently this is fixed in ASP.NET 4.5.

Source:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FormsAuthenticationOnASPNETSitesWithTheGoogleChromeBrowserOnIOS.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Cookies` are probably disabled.  Forms Authentication relies on `Cookies`.

Comment: Cookies weren't disabled, I checked all that.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile chrome occasionally tends to do that with mvc3 and mvc4. I'm not sure if anyone yet knows why. Having cookies on and setting the UseCookies in Web.Config doesn't help. Furthermore, I'm not sure if Web Forms is affected. But since I've seen this only in Mobile Chrome, I'd say it's something Google needs to fix.

Comment: mmm.. Im going to try this:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FormsAuthenticationOnASPNETSitesWithTheGoogleChromeBrowserOnIOS.aspx